# How can I get the current logged in user in Pinax?

Tags: django, pinax

I'm using Pinax, and *account* type which offer the account management system.

How can I get the current logged in user in my view?

Answer (score 3):

You get the logged in user in Pinax the same way as you get the current logged in user in Django. If you configure the Django auth app correctly, then the user is available as `request.user`.

```
def my_view(request):
    user = request.user
```